# Facebook's URL Linter & The Open Graph Protocol

Tags: web-scraping, facebook-opengraph

I see many pages out there without OG tags (i.e. tags as specified here: http://ogp.me/), yet the Facebook URL Linter seems to be able to get an image and description for them.

For example - you won't see any OG tags (or even other relevant meta tags that could be used to infer said data) on the home page of:
http://www.magicka2.com

But when you take it through Facebook, it finds a description and image:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.magicka2.com%2F

So, what am I missing? The image and description they get seem very specific (and correct). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In case of missing Open-Graph tags, Facebook analyses the page and extracts the image for which it thinks it suits the best and what text should be the description text. They follow some "rules" to determine which picture, but there is also some AI involved and it's part of their systems.

If you want to control which image/title/description your page will show when shared, I would advise to always provide OG-details explicitly.